# How to configure Frontend and Backend on LEMP stack

Tags: angular, laravel, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have configured a server and now I can deploy the both front-end (Angular 6) and backend (Laravel 5.7) to the production server that I created on Vultr LEMP stack. 

Frontend deployed to `/var/www/frontend` and backend deployed to `/var/www/backend` now I want to use backend APIs with frontend but in the `sites-available` in nginx I used `root` as `/var/www/frontend` so How can I configure backend to working?

Comment: Can you share the config you have so far?

Comment: Finally I managed to fix my issue, I connected a domain to my server and I added a sub domain and configured it in sites-available then pointed it to my backend (api.mydomainname.com) and main domain I have my frontend. 

thanks @SamuelP.